# How to fix encoding while reading json response in android?

Tags: java, android, encoding, character-encoding

I am calling an API which returns a `JSON` response. While reading the `JSON` response there are some places where data has some special characters. I want to exclude these special characters while reading the response in an object. The `JSON` response looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"title":"PSY - GANGNAM STYLE (\uac15\ub0a8\uc2a4\ud0c0\uc77c) M\/V","content":All rights reserved."}]}
```

The Java code is this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "ISO-8859-1"), 8);
```

When I read the title key from the response, it gives me these special characters as well which I don't want. How do get rid of those? Do i need to specify some other encoding?

Data Source :http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=920adeb2e95c15877e29dc678aa78dd7&_render=json&n=1

Comment: (\uac15\ub0a8\uc2a4\ud0c0\uc77c) M\/V  --- these

Comment: They're not special, just Unicode.  Do you want to remove them or get the encoding right?  If you want to remove them, is the string you receive *always* the same format?

Comment: I need encoding right becoz string is not always same.I have even tried UTF-8 as well but no luck.

Comment: I think you don't need to remove Unicode characters because it my be the important data.

Comment: JSON *should* be UTF-8 so I guess the server is returning a bad response.  Please show the response header.

Comment: @Simon I have edited my question and added the link from which I am taking JSON data.Please review and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an encoding issue (like UTF-8), it's a JavaScript syntax issue.  The "`\uac15`", for example, is JavaScript syntax that represents the Unicode character U+AC15, which is "강".  Together, those escaped characters are the name of the song written in Hangul (Korean): "강남스타일".

It's normal and OK for your Java string to contain the backslash escape sequences.  When you run that string though a JSON reader, you should get a JSON object containing the actual Hangul characters.

---

In response to your comment about getting wrong output from a JSON reader, that depends on what JSON library you're using (and how you're using it), which you didn't specify in the question.  Here's an example that works for me using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) 2.1.0:

```
public final class JsonTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String json = "\"PSY - GANGNAM STYLE (\\uac15\\ub0a8\\uc2a4\\ud0c0\\uc77c) M\\/V\"";
        System.out.println("JSON: " + json);

        try {
            // ObjectMapper is from Jackson 2.1 databind library.
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final String decoded = mapper.readValue(json, String.class);
            System.out.println("Decoded: " + decoded);
        }
        catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its giving me "PSY - GANGNAM STYLE (ê°ë¨ì¤íì¼) M/V" instead of  "PSY - GANGNAM STYLE (강남스타일)" when I am running through JSON reader and converting it to JSON object.Plz help

Comment: Please try the example code I added.  I suspect you may actually be getting the right string from your JSON reader, but encountering some sort of encoding mix-up in your output code afterward.